# Drawing user input on Image JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Suppose you have an app that displays user graphic (some kind of image) then you want to allow the user to draw some lines on this image. I have the following questions regarding such situation:

How would you accomplish that? 
How would you get pixel coordinates for the image from the user drag events? 
How would you update the image in real time?

Answer (score 4):

I will give you an example of the **exact opposite** [erasing the Image on JavaFX]
which I suppose **will be enough as a starter point** for you:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.CycleMethod;
import javafx.scene.paint.LinearGradient;
import javafx.scene.paint.Stop;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class EraseImageonCanvas extends Application {
    private Pane root = new Pane();
    private void setCanvas(Canvas canvas, Image img) {
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.drawImage(img, 0, 0,canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Erasing the Image");
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(400, 400);
        drawBackground(rect);
        root.getChildren().add(rect);
        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(200, 200);
        canvas.setTranslateX(100);
        canvas.setTranslateY(100);
        //For local images use         
        //image = new Image(getClass().getResource(#Path#).openStream());
        final Image image = new Image(
                "http://kyllo.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Faroeste-Cabloco.jpg"
              );
        setCanvas(canvas,image);
        final GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        // Clear away portions as the user drags the mouse
        canvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                gc.clearRect(e.getX() - 2, e.getY() - 2, 5, 5);
            }
        });

        // Reset the Canvas when the user double-clicks
        canvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent t) {            
                if (t.getClickCount() >1) {
                    setCanvas(canvas, image);
                }  
            }
        });

        // Add the Canvas to the Scene, and show the Stage
        root.getChildren().add(canvas);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

     //Draws the background with a RadialGradient 
    private void drawBackground(Rectangle rect) {
        rect.setFill(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 1, 1, true,
                CycleMethod.REFLECT,
                new Stop(0, Color.RED),
                new Stop(1, Color.YELLOW)));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Download it on [gist](https://gist.github.com/kyllopardiun/a86d8f7e38164c3912cd)

Comment: Thx but it's all done in the main thread and there are no bindings in your solutions for auto update, In your scenario it is not a problem but consider a task that need to do a lot of computations. The app would hang

Answer (score 2):

this [Canvas tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/canvas/jfxpub-canvas.htm) shows exactly what you want to accomplish in the "Interacting with the User" section.

It shows how you can add an EventHandler to the Canvas to handle [MouseEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html) such as `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED`. The [GraphicsContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html) is then used to get the x and y coordinates and draw on the canvas.

In order to use the Canvas outside the main Application class, you'd declare the Canvas in your .fxml file as such:

```
<BorderPane fx:controller="controllers.MyController" 
  xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <Canvas fx:id="drawArea" height="..." width="..."/>
</BorderPane>
```

Then, on your MyController class:

```
public class MyController implements Initializable {
  @FXML
  private Canvas drawArea;
  private GraphicsContext gc;

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    gc = drawArea.getGraphicsContext2D();
    // Java 8 syntax, beware!
    drawArea.setOnMouseDragged(event -> gc.fillRect(event.getX(), event.getY(), 5, 5));
  }
}
```